# Generate file and upload in back ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code that generates an excel

```
book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
sheet1 = book.create_worksheet

.
.
.

send_data file_contents.string.force_encoding("binary"), filename: file_name
```

but I need to upload the file as an attachment to a comment
without downloading it
from the same back upload the file.

```
TaskComment.create(task_execution_id: params[:bank_reconciliation][:task_execution],
                   user_id: 3, activity_step: params[:bank_reconciliation][:activity_id], comment: "comenteario",
                   file1: **here file**)
```

please help me

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages. We need a better example of your code showing the attempt, and whatever error you're encountering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
> sheet1 = book.create_worksheet
>
> sheet1.row(0).push "", "CHEQUES COBRADOS Y NO CONTABILIZADOS ", "$"
>
> temp_file = Tempfile.new(filename)
>
> book.write temp_file.path
>
> upload = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new({
>   :filename => "conciliacion_bancaria.xls",
>   #:type => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
>   :type => "application/excel",
>   :tempfile => temp_file,
> })
>
> TaskComment.create( file1: upload)
> ```

it worked for me